# how to put publisher and subscriber in a single Node?

Tags: ros, callback, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i am writing a node which subscribes to `/scan topic` make some calculations and according to the calculated values it publishes different messages on the `/robotState topic` in the callback function.

Here is my code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>

void switcherCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    ros::NodeHandle p;
    ros::Publisher state_pub = p.advertise<std_msgs::String>("robotState",1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
    while(ros::ok())
    {
    int f=0;
    for(int i=0; i<msg->ranges.size(); i++){
        if(msg->ranges[i]<1.5f){
            f=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(f==1){
        std_msgs::String msg;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss<<"1";
        msg.data = ss.str();
        state_pub.publish(msg);
    }else{
        std_msgs::String msg;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss<<"0";
        msg.data = ss.str();
        state_pub.publish(msg);
    }
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "switcher");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("scan", 1000, switcherCallback);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

But whenever i executes the code it shows the following error:

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

i am just wandering why this error is occurred and how can i put both publisher and subscriber in a single node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202451/how-to-put-publisher-and-subscriber-in-a-single-node?/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2015-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jie Sky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20509/jie-sky/) on 2015-05-06**:
hi Aarif ，I am doing the same work,but it do not work .can you tell me how you make it work? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't call `ros::spinOnce()` inside the callback. What it does is that it checks the subscriber queue, then calls your callback again, so that now you're calling the callback recursively. Instead, process the single message and exit the callback, which will drop you back into the `ros::spin()` call in `main()`.

Also, you shouldn't re-create the publisher every time you want to publish a message (inside the callback). Instead, create it once (in main) and use it inside the callback. Otherwise, the subscribers won't be able to read the message before the publisher is destroyed again (when exiting the callback).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2015-02-06**:
Thanks @Martin Günther, it worked.

**Comment by [Jie Sky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20509/jie-sky/) on 2015-05-06**:
hi Aarif ，I am doing the same work,but it do not work .can you tell me how you make it work? thanks a lot

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2015-08-26**:
hi @Jie Sky, do exactly as explained in the answer. i hope it will work for you too... :)